# Android Activity Dialog freezes the screen once exited until back is pressed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to learn a bit about Android development so I have created an Android activity for displaying a dialog with two buttons. That is as simple as the following:

```
class DialogWindow extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Dialog Window");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to save");
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save"),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    doThis();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    doThat();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I am testing it so the methods `doThis()` and `doThat()` so far only displays their corresponding `Toast` messages.

**The problem**

is that whatever `Button` I press, the `Dialog` is closed and the previuos `Activity` screen is displayed. But I cannot interact with it anymore until I press the back button: then I can interact again without problems with my activity.

Can you please tell me why this is happening? Of course in my plan I want the dialog window to close making the app immediately responsive. Why with the code above I have to press back?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried  alertDialog.create().show(); ? Although there might not be a difference. I'll read a bit more through the code hoping to find an error.

Comment: Actually, it is probably because you create the dialog and show it in onCreate(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508747/alertdialog-with-custom-view-in-oncreate

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an invisible Activity (since you don't call setContentView) that spawns the Dialog.
Once the dialog is dismissed, the Activity is still there.
Hence why you need to back out of the DialogWindow activity before resuming your previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

Calling alertDialog.cancel() instead of alertDialog.dismiss() solved this issue for me.